# How do I keep a table in one Word document that shows the details about AWS EC2 instances updated?

Tags: microsoft-word, amazon-web-services, export, report, embedding

I have an AWS account on which I have a few EC2 instances running. For documentation purposes, I have to maintain a Microsoft Word document where the list of such EC2 instances and its details are provided as a table.

As of now, I export the details from AWS console; clean them up; copy and paste one detail after another into the word document.  Once I have prepared this document, any changes happening on the EC2 instances are not reflected in the document and the document becomes outdated.

Like how I can update a "Table of Contents" at my will, I should be able to update this table which will keep the data updated always. Is there any way to do this without using VBA macros in my Word document?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an aws-cli [ec2 describe-intances](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)(take a look at the examples) with a proper combination of **filters** and **queries** based on your requirements, even use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter and tweak it even more in case the default filters are not enough for you) and then save the output to a csv.
Once you have the command ready to go and it satisfies the requirements, you could potentially create a scheduled task to run it every hour or so, depending on how often you want to update the file.